# Flutter App freezes when keyboard is launched

Tags: ios, google-maps, flutter, mobile-development

I'm trying to build an IOS application with flutter that uses Google maps. However when I tap the search box and open the keyboard to search for a place the application freezes and I can't even type. This is in a simulator as I don't have a physical iPhone to test it with. I am a flutter beginner and can't tell what is going wrong(suspecting I messed something up). I have researched on this and found that a previous version of flutter had an issue with the IOS keyboard lagging but there was no mention of the application being completely frozen. I commented out onChanged thinking it had something to do with the freeze.

```
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  Completer<GoogleMapController> _controller = Completer();

  static const LatLng _center = const LatLng(45.521563, -122.677433);

  String searchValue = "";
  String _mapStyle;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    rootBundle.loadString('assets/map_style.txt').then((string) {
      _mapStyle = string;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CupertinoPageScaffold(
        navigationBar: CupertinoNavigationBar(
          backgroundColor: GlobalAppConstants.appMainColor,
        ),
        child: GestureDetector(
          onTap:() {
            FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(new FocusNode());
          },
          child: Stack(
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                child: GoogleMap(
                  initialCameraPosition:
                      CameraPosition(target: _center, zoom: 1.0),
                  mapType: MapType.normal,
                  onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {
                    controller.setMapStyle(_mapStyle);
                    _controller.complete(controller);
                  },
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                color: Color.fromRGBO(255, 255, 255, 0.7),
              ),
              Align(
                alignment: Alignment(0.0, -0.5),
                child: Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text(
                      'My Text',
                      style:
                          TextStyle(fontSize: 30, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                    ),
                    Container(
                      padding: EdgeInsetsDirectional.only(top: 20.0),
                    ),
                    Text(
                      'Search Country',
                      style: TextStyle(
                          color: GlobalAppConstants.appMainColor,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                    ),
                    Container(
                      width: 140.0,
                      padding: EdgeInsetsDirectional.only(top: 0.0),
                      child: Divider(
                        thickness: 7.0,
                        color: GlobalAppConstants.appMainColor,
                      ),
                    ),
                    Container(
                      padding: EdgeInsetsDirectional.only(
                          start: 10.0, end: 10.0, top: 10.0),
                      height: 50,
                      child: CupertinoTextField(
                        placeholder: 'Search Country',
                        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                            horizontal: 10.0, vertical: 0.4),
                        prefix: Container(
                          padding: EdgeInsetsDirectional.only(start: 10.0),
                          child: Icon(
                            CupertinoIcons.search,
                            color: CupertinoColors.black,
                            size: 22.0,
                          ),
                        ),
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: CupertinoColors.white,
                          boxShadow: [
                            BoxShadow(
                              color: CupertinoColors.black,
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
//                        onChanged: (String value) {
////                      setState(() {
////                        searchValue = value;
////                      });
//                        },
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

I did add `<key>io.flutter.embedded_views_preview</key>
    <string>YES</string>`
to my Info.plist file. Which seemed to be of discussion in the forums that I found. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I think I found what the issue was, so for the benefit of future viewers - simply try to restart your iOS simulator. I wasted so many hours trying to chase some elusive bug and eventually it was just a simulator issue...

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how I fixed this. Ran flutter clean a bunch of times. And changed and unchanged the ios version in the Podfile. Flutter magic I guess. Also deleted all content and settings on the Simulator at some point.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. App (iOS) entirely freezes as soon as the keyboard tries to open. The space for the keyboard is already created, but the app freezes before it shows, and there is no way to get out of this. No clue how to solve this...

Comment: You can try what I did. run `flutter clean` change ios version in podfile to 13. Then go into xcode and change the target sdk in there to 13 too. Not sure what fixed it though.